# How to capture runtime parameters with extended event?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events, parameter

I use rpc_completed event in order to capture executed sprocs. I am also to view the statement and passed parameters by using the following way:

right-click extended event -> Watch Live Data and finally see statement+parameters

However I want to see the captured data in table format, but I wasn't able to implement it. When I run below query it shows statement without parameters. How can I see parameters in the table form? Need your suggestions.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#capture_waits_data') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #capture_waits_data
SELECT CAST(target_data as xml) AS targetdata
INTO #capture_waits_data
FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets xet
JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions xes
ON xes.address = xet.event_session_address
WHERE xes.name = 'LongRunningQueries'
AND xet.target_name = 'ring_buffer';
--*/
/**********************************************************/
SELECT
CONVERT(datetime2,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,xed.event_data.value('(@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2')),DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) AS datetime_local,
xed.event_data.value('(@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS event_type,
xed.event_data.value('(data[@name="statement"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS statement,
xed.event_data.value('(data[@name="duration"]/value)[1]', 'bigint')/1000 AS duration_ms,
xed.event_data.value('(data[@name="physical_reads"]/value)[1]', 'bigint') AS physical_reads,
xed.event_data.value('(data[@name="logical_reads"]/value)[1]', 'bigint') AS logical_reads
FROM #capture_waits_data
CROSS APPLY targetdata.nodes('//RingBufferTarget/event') AS xed (event_data)
WHERE 1=1 and xed.event_data.value('(action[@name="username"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(255)') <> 'NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT'
```

Here is actual used extended event:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [LongRunningQueries] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed(
    ACTION(package0.collect_system_time,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([duration]>(4000000) AND [sqlserver].[database_name]='mydb')),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed(
    ACTION(package0.collect_system_time,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([duration]>(4000000) AND [sqlserver].[database_name]='mydb')) 
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer(SET max_events_limit=(0),max_memory=(102400))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=5 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the procedures are being called, you should absolutely see the parameter values in the 'statement' column. [I have a blog post](https://www.scarydba.com/2018/09/24/extended-events-and-stored-procedure-parameter-values/) that demonstrates exactly this issue. There's literally nothing magical to make this happen. It's just a part of the statement.

Now, to make the statement appear in the grid in the Live Data Viewer, you can either right click in the details pain and select the menu choice to show the statement, or, you can select the column picker from the toolbar. [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDtXjewvqmM&t=409s) showing how that works.

Comment: Yes Sir, you are right. I didn't pay attention at first time. Now I rechecked and was able to see actual parameters.